# What is the meaning of checking the same condition two times with if(cond) esle if(sameCond)?

Tags: javascript, game-engine

I was reading a game engine called Panda.js.
There was a method in the core checking if Full screen supported by the browser or not but I didn't understand this code :

```
if (this.system.canvas.requestFullscreen)
    this.system.canvas.requestFullscreen();
else if (this.system.canvas.requestFullScreen)
    this.system.canvas.requestFullScreen();
```

Comment: Most probably this is a bug.

Comment: Looks like an error to me, I can't see why the second block would ever get executed unless it is some sort of bug workaround where the first call to this.system.canvas.requestFullscreen is falsey in some browsers but triggers it to exist in subsequent calls..

Answer (score 4):

If you look closely, you will see they are not the same condition. The two methods are different because one is capital and one is not. I'm guessing the developers made one lower case to denote that it is not full screen, and capital for full screen. Either way it is not the same condition.

```
if (this.system.canvas.requestFullscreen)
    this.system.canvas.requestFullscreen();
else if (this.system.canvas.requestFullScreen)
    this.system.canvas.requestFullScreen();`
```

The S in Screen changes.

Comment: I guess they were clients of an API which they were unsure of the casing that the API's function would be. That way, they test if the functions are defined before calling them.

Comment: The reason isn't to do with whether or not it's fullscreen, it's due to [a division in the naming standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API#Prefixing).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I just giving it my best guess. @PatrickRoberts

Answer (score -1):

In general, you wouldn't use the exact same condition in an `if` and `else`. Unless evaluating the condition changes the result of subsequent calls--arguably a poor design choice--the `else` block will never be executed and the condition will be needlessly tested twice when it evaluates to `false`.

That said, @Brendan is correct: this code does not have identical conditions. See his answer for details.